# How to draw a 2D Image using OpenGL

Tags: c++, image, opengl, 2d, render

I've started learning OpenGL a few days ago, and I'm mainly focusing OpenGL on 2D game development...

I've learned the basics of OpenGL - Creating a window, handling keyboard input.

What I did not find in tutorials (and did not found a clear solution in the net), is how to draw 2D image (such as a "player" image in a casual 2D game) using OpenGL.

I've learned XNA before, and remembered there was a structure called 2DTexture, though I did not find any in OpenGL..

I'm not looking toward 3D currently in OpenGL...

Edit:

if it makes it anyway easier, I can have the image's RGB in an array (array sized [WIDTH][HEIGHT], every cell contains the Pixel's R, G, B

Comment: Build a 3D object but for example only in the X, Y plane. Where z is zero so its 2d.

Comment: and how can I render an Image in OpenGL in general?

Comment: By using [textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture). I believe old NeHe [tutorial series](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/) are still reasonable thing for learning.

Comment: texture mapping is the magic word. I think the function is glTextImage2d( ... ). What window library do you use? I had good experiences with glfw http://www.glfw.org/

Comment: You'll need to draw a square and then texture map it with the image you want to show. If you work through the [open.gl](http://open.gl/) tutorial series it'll teach you how to do it in modern OpenGL (and much more). I don't recommend NeHe as it's using immediate mode which has been deprecated for years (and is really slow).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, OpenGL is a much lower level API than XNA and it is not primarily focused on 2D rendering.

In older versions of OpenGL, the function [`glDrawPixels()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml) could serve the purpose of old school [bit blitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit) on the screen, but is was ridiculously inefficient.

The efficient way of rendering 2D images, like sprites for a 2D game, on modern OpenGL is by mean of drawing a flat quadrilateral with an [orthographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) camera and applying a texture on top of it.

I can't remember any tutorial right now that covers 2D rendering specifically, but I think it would be best for you to first get a good grasp on texture mapping and the basics of polygon rendering. For this, [ogldev](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/) is a good starting point; [opengl-tutorial.org](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/) is also a great source.

Comment: Is there a good, higher API Level than OpenGL, who would suit me better for 2D rendering?

XNA is nice, but I'd like to program in C++.